# Dropping the less significant terms in the middle of calculating time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

We know that for some algorithm with time complexity of lets say `T(n) = n^2 + n + 1` we can drop the less significant terms and say that it has a worst case of `O(n^2)`.

What about when we're in the middle of calculating time complexity of an algorithm such as `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n + log(n)`? Can we just drop the less significant terms and just say `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n = O(n log(n))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that  `T(n) = n^2 + n + 1` is a closed form expression, in simple terms it means you can inject some value for n and you will get the value of this whole expression.

on the other hand `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n + log(n)` is a [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), it means this expression is defined recursively, to get a closed form expression you will have to solve the recurrence relation.

Now to answer your question, in general we drop lower order terms and coefficients when we can clearly see the highest order term, in `T(n) = n^2 + n + 1` its n^2. but in a recurrence relation there is no such highest order term, because its not a closed form expression.

but one thing to observe is that highest order term in the closed form expression of a recurrence relation would be ***result of depth of recurrence tree multiplied with the highest order term in recurrence relation***, so in your case it would be `depthOf(2T(n/2)) * n`, this would result in something like `logn*n`, so you can say that in terms of big O notation its `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: I see. In that case, can I take a wild guess and say that `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n + log(n)` is equivalent to the sum of both `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n` and `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log(n)`? So in this case it would be `T(n) = n log(n) + n` and then we can drop the less significant terms and say that this is O(n log(n)?

Comment: Don't work based on guesses. best method would be to solve the recurrence and get a closed form expression, then you can clearly see the highest order term, but if you solve enough recurrence relations then you develop a general understanding of what would be the closed form expression.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, yes, you can safely discard the dominated (log n) term. In general, you can do this any time you only need the asymptotic behaviour rather than the exact formula.

When you apply the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) to solve a recurrence relation like

> T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)

asymptotically, then you don't need an exact formula for f(n), just the asymptotic behaviour, because that's how the Master theorem works.

In your example, a = 2, b = 2, so the critical exponent is c = 1. Then the Master theorem tells us that T(n) is in Θ(n log n) because f(n) = n + log n, which is in Θ(n<sup>c</sup>) = Θ(n).

We would have reached the same conclusion using f(n) = n, because that's also in Θ(n). Applying the theorem only requires knowing the asymptotic behaviour of f(n), so *in this context* it's safe to discard dominated terms which don't affect f(n)'s asymptotic behaviour.